# ASP.NET Core: Access and Re-use Configuration Object

Tags: asp.net-core

In my Startup.cs, I have the following boilerplate code:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

What I want to do is access and re-use the already-built `Configuration` object with a Controller elsewhere in my project without having to build a new configuration object over there. How can I do that or is it even possible?

Comment: The question is: Why would you want do this? I can't think for a reason why you'd need the `IConfigurationRoot` element anywhere except curing startup/bootstrapping. You're supposed to read the config there and deserialize it into `IOptions<MyOptions>` types, which can be injected anywhere

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few alternatives:

1. Store the configuration object in a global variable.

   - Pro: simple.
   - Con: creates coupling and makes everyone aware of the `Configuration` object. No DI. No type safety.
2. Add the configuration object to the DI container and consume it where you need it.

   - Pro: decoupling. Supports DI.
   - Con: you make other components aware of configuration. No type safety.
3. Create an options object either by using `IOptions` or by using `ConfigurationBinder` and add it to the container.

   - Pro: nice architecture where each component knows only about the options object. Supports DI. Type safe.
   - Con: more code.

For a Hello World size app, option #1 works just fine. For a real world application I would definitely consider #3.

Comment: Alternative #3 IOptions is the way to go. It looks like the proper convention. I just wasn't aware of it. I followed this tutorial: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-5-configuration-and-ioptions. I did run into a pretty significant obstacle whereby Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions needed to be added to the project.json to get the tutorial to work properly.